# How to decode JSON to list of model objects

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I'm decoding a JSON http respond to a list of model objects using the code bellow. It just works fine, however I'm asking me how I could rewrite the code to

1. not use the type cast 'as List'
2. replace the type 'dynamic' with the more specific type 'CodeModel'

```
final List<CodeModel> codes = (json.decode(response.body) as List)
  .map((dynamic model) => CodeModel.fromJson(model))
  .toList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should, in general, avoid overt static typing where the analyzer can figure it out for you.

You can replace your code with:

```
  final codes =
      json.decode(response.body).map<CodeModel>((m) => CodeModel.fromJson(m)).toList();

  print(codes.runtimeType);
```

There's no need to specify the type of `codes` - it can be inferred.

Changing `.map` to `.map<CodeModel>` tells the analyzer that the lambda will return a `CodeModel`, so the `toList` will produce a list of them.

The print line prints `List<CodeModel>` as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this works exactly as expected!